# Asynchronous RenderScript

Tags: asynchronous, kernel, renderscript

I do not really understand the asynchronous behavior of RenderScript. There are several examples:

```
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) root(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
void root(const uchar4 *v_in, uchar4 *v_out) {
  ...
}
```

I do not know which to use with `foreach_root()`. And even, after returning from invocation, results are there synchronously. However, documentation mentions the asynchronous functioning everywhere...

How should this be used correctly for parallelism of kernels?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21367498/295004

Comment: Thanks. I do not have enough reputations to comment there. So, here: copyTo will block java code similar to finish? That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your first kernel example needs a uchar4 return value:

```
uchar4 u4;
u4 = (uchar4){x,y,x+y,x-y};  // using the x,y from kernel, for example
return u4;
```

where your second kernel example puts it´s result direct at the *v_out pointer´s position (a * indicates a pointer).

```
uchar4 u4: 
...
*v_out = u4;
```

What is the difference ? Nothing, as long as your kernel result is 
a renderscript primitive (uchar4, float2, int, double3 ...) which can be "returned". This will be in most cases.

And you are right: as long as the kernels are running (and filling the out allocation with data), *the actual thread will be blocked at the next point the out allocation will be used*. Consider this simple benchmark

```
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
myScript.forEach_root(.....    // triggers (starts) the script parallel / asynchron
long t2 = System.nanoTime();
// HERE is the blocking !
aOut.copyTo(bitmap);           // aOut : Allocation object
long t3 = System.nanoTime();
```

t1 gets the starttime, then the script is triggered (asynchron, parallel). Immidiat after the "trigger" t2 is taken. The asynchron running script hasn´t finished yet.
t2 will only be sightly greater than t1 (a few nanoseconds).

**Then** the out allocation is used to copy it´s data to a bitmap.
Before **this line** the code blocks until all kernels are finished.
Finally t3 marks the end.

The whole computing time (script + aOut.copyTo..) is t3-t1 , **not** t2-t1 .